# Copy files but lose folder structure

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I'm trying to copy everything in my css directory, including any nested folders and files in those folders.

```
copy: {
        main: {
            options: {
                expand: true
            },
            files: [
                { src: 'public/static/css/**', dest: '../../../'}
            ]
        }
    }
```

The above works but it appears to be keeping the directory structure.

So in my root where the files are copied to I have:

```
>public>static>css>styles.css
>public static>css>nested-folder>styles.css
```

But I would just like to have:

> styles.css

```
>nested-folder>styles.css
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Set the current working directory, `cwd`, in the options.  There are some instructions in the [Grunt docs](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expand) and your `copy` options would look something like:

```
copy: {
        main: {
            options: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'public/static/css',
                src : [ '**' ],
                dest: '../../../'
            }
        }
    }
```